# Startup of the worker pool in zone failed with the error "ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED"

Tags: resources, pool, dataflow, zone

I am running a simple dataflow job and get the below error. I am able to run the job only in the East Asia region. All other 5 regions give me the below error.

> Startup of the worker pool in zone us-central1-a failed to bring up any of
>   the desired 1 workers.
>   ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED:
>   The zone 'projects/lmcdemo1111/zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. 
>   Try a different zone, or try again later

Any thoughts on how to fix this?